# Can I link an MS Access Application to Postgre SQL on a Linux Server? Can / Should I use ODBC?

Tags: ms-access, postgresql, odbc, windows-server

I write MS Access / VB / SQL Applications, customized. One of my clients has a truly massive Access application I wrote them, and their number of active users have just expanded to over 15. Running into more data corruption issues, I am recommending they port to an SQL backend for stability. (Of course).

They would prefer to invest in a less expensive option and go with a Linux Server. I have used ODBC to hook an Access front to SQL backend plenty of times. But I have never touched Postgre.

I am looking for comprehensive detailed data on if this is a good strategic solution for a design plan, or if it is even a possibility. Perhaps there is an easier solution and I am barking up the wrong tree...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is absolutely possible.  I've not run into any major issues - the biggest I had was getting the Postgres boolean's to match up correctly - but it all depends on how you setup the ODBC connection and the actual application.  I've found the ODBC connection stable and usable.  If you really anticipate a larger number of users, you really ought to consider rewriting the whole app into something other than Access.

Overall, I'd definitely recommend Postgres as a backend via ODBC.  Once you get used to a few of the differences, a lot of people really end up enjoying Postgres as a DB.

Comment: A lot of experienced Access developers have had great success with PostgreSQL. I find it an attractive back end as it seems more robust than MySQL, but have never actually had opportunity to use it in an Access app (as opposed to MySQL), though I would not hesitate for a moment to use it.

Comment: David, this sounds like you've used MySQL with Access.  How as it?

Comment: Only relatively trivially, and with MySQL 4.x. Access can't deal with tables having full-text indexes, for one.

Comment: im using msaccess with mysql and it works quite well, as long as you respect the MySQL environment (no using special characters in data, as well as table and field names - stick to unicode).